# How to store data in AzureData Lake in a sequential manner and reading it sequentially in flink?

Tags: azure, apache-flink, flink-streaming, azure-data-lake

I am using flink custom sink to store the data in a file in Azure Data Lake and custom source to read the data from the same file in azure data lake.But when I am trying to store the data to azure data lake file the data are not stored sequentially i.e) the data which I am sending is stored in random way not in order which I am sending. When I am trying to use parallelism = 1 then only single thread will be writing to the Azure Data Lake and it is very slow in writing.

When I am reading through custom source in flink the data is not read sequentially . How to achieve these both? Could anyone help me in this?

Comment: Flink will read and write data in a parallel way from multiple threads. What does ordering mean in your context. Can you explain this part a bit better?

Comment: @AmitKulkarni. I am fetching the data from kafka topic in flink and inserting the data to a file in Azure Data Lake. But the writing of data into the file in azure data lake in not in the same order as it is fetched from the kafka topic. In my application the order in which it is fetched and writing to data lake is important because when I read data once again from the file in azure data lake it should be in the same order as it is fetched from kafka. Is there any way I could insert to file in azure data lake the same order as i fetch from kafka? Could you help me in this?

Comment: Won't data be fetched by the Flink sink in parallel by multiple threads? Every thread will write the data in parallel and you will not be able to control the order in which each thread appends data (assuming you are using concurrent appends).